# Хочу попробовать применить else вместе с if,но каждый раз выскакивает ошибка

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()

{

int a = 1;

int b = 2;

int c = 3;

int d = 4;

int a1 = 5;

int b2 = 6;

int c3 = 78;

int d9 = 9;

    int sum = - 1 + 2 - 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 78 + 9;

    int sum2 = - 1 + 2;

    if(b2>=a)

    else{b>=a

    cout <<"hellol word\n;"

    }

    else{b2<=d9

    cout<<programing<< endl;

    }

    cout <<sum<<endl;

    cout << sum2<< endl;

     return 0;

}

Вот мой измененный код
```

Comment: **Что именно** вы хотите добиться `else`, поясните словами, будет понятно, как вам помочь...

Comment: прошу добавить else

Answer (score 2):

По вашей просьбе "добавить else".

```
if(b2>=a){
    cout <<sum<<endl;
    cout << sum2<< endl;
    cin.get()
    return 0;
  } else{}
```

Это устраивает? Вряд ли.
Не может инструмент быть целью, он - *средство*.

Comment: По моему он записывает какие то операторы в  теле else и ничего не возвращает, потому и получает ошибку. Нужно все делать до возвращения

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Ну, он пишет вроде бы об ошибках (компиляции?)...

Comment: @Harry, Я так люблю, когда Вы отвечаете, не зная верный ответ или нет, но в итоге любым путем стараетесь помочь:))))

Comment: @entithat Но ведь человек, кажется, и в самом деле хочет разобраться, нет? В общем, не то чтоб помочь, скорее, заставить думать. В данном случае ответ, на мой взгляд, неверный (скорее всего), но он должен заставить задуматься. Я дал шанс в комментарии. Разместить код в комментарии, увы, практически нереально, приходится идти в ответ. Дальше - если ТС задумается - ответ будет переделываться и на какой-то итерации рефакторинга :) обретет смысл и полезность. Нет - значит, это очередной никому не нужный вопрос. А вообще главное - понимания не самого языка, а процесса программирования :)

Comment: @entithat Поэтому у меня не такая уж редкость ситуация, когда я голосую за закрытие вопроса и пытаюсь ответить одновременно. Поймет, исправится, уточнит ТЗ, чтоб не писать в ответ Хз - отзову голос за закрытие. не поймет - ну. туда такому вопросу и дорога...

Comment: @Harry, я Вас поддерживаю. Вопросы должны быть полезны. И на счёт заставить думать, это верный ход:)

Comment: Здравствуйте,я просто новичок и учусь програмировать.У меня появилась идея сначала просто научиться писать программу для сложения чисел а потом с каждым новым уроком добавлять полученные знания в программу.Я понимаю что добавлять оператор else и if бессмысленно так как уже понятно какие переменные будут истинны а какие ложные.Если у тебя есть ещё способ обучения,то предлагай буду только рад

Comment: Просто посмотрите в учебнике. Общий вид примерно таков - `if (что-то) { делать, если да } else { делать, если нет }`. Если вы пишете именно так, и выскакивают ошибки - то давайте разбираться: показывайте точный код, приведший к ошибкам, чтоб можно было понять, где именно вы ошибаетесь, Без этого получается что-то вроде попытки учить, как правильно прыгать с вышки - а потом выясняется, что в бассейне нет воды :)

Comment: Извини, меня,но я тебя обожаю.Просто я даже наверное не особо осознавал некорректность своего вопроса,но твои примеры отлично помогают это понять.Хоть у меня очень плохие оценки в школе по информатике и алгебре и многим другим предметам.Кстати мой учебник это приложение на телефоне по названием SoloLearn.В нем можно изучать основы и так же писать программы в нем

Comment: nclude <iostream>                   
 using namespace std; 
int main()
{
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = 4;
int a1 = 5;
int b2 = 6;
int c3 = 78;
int d9 = 9;
    int sum = - 1 + 2 - 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 78 + 9;
    int sum2 = - 1 + 2;
    if(b2>=a){
else{sum2 <=5
    cout <<sum<<endl;
    cout << sum2<< endl;
     return 0;
  } 
} 
}

Comment: Извини,пишу с телефона не могу разделить строки

Comment: >>if(b2>=a){ else{<< неверный порядок токенов {}. Если блок "true" пустой, то закройте его как полагается, а не оставляйте открытым. if(b2>=a) {} else { ... }

Comment: Похоже я чего-то не понимаю.В учебнике написано.Оператор if может использоваться вместе с оператором else, который выполняется, когда условие ложно. 
Синтаксис:. if (condition) {
  statements
}
else {
 statements
}.           Код проверит условие: 
- Если оно истинно, то код внутри выражения if будет выполнен. 
- Если оно ложно, то будет выполнен код внутри выражения else.

Comment: Смотрите - `if (aaa) { bbb } else { ccc }`/ Вы пишете `if (aaa) { else { ccc }}` - видите разницу в структуре скобок? Если вы хотите выполнить **только** часть `else`, то делайте так: `if (aaa) {} else { ccc }`, но еще лучше - использовать *обратное условие* - `if (!(aaa)) { ccc }`

Comment: Harry, попробовал использовать else по твоей схеме,но ничего не выходит. (что-то) { делать, если да } else { делать, если нет }

Comment: #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = 4;
int a1 = 5;
int b2 = 6;
int c3 = 78;
int d9 = 9;
    int sum = - 1 + 2 - 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 78 + 9;
    int sum2 = - 1 + 2;
    if(b2>=a)
    else{b>=a
    cout <<"hellol word\n;"
    }
    else{b2<=d9
    cout<<programing<< endl;
    }
    cout <<sum<<endl;
    cout << sum2<< endl;
     return 0;
}

Вот код

Comment: Блин,я не могу его разделить

Comment: Текущий код смотрите на верху.Скажите в чем дело

Comment: >> if(b2>=a) else{ ... } else{ ... } << лишнее слово else вначале

Comment: Всё же, настоятельно рекомендую начать с книги.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {    
          int a = 1;
          int b = 2;
          int c = 3;
          int d = 4;
          int a1 = 5;
          int b2 = 6;
          int c3 = 78;
          int d9 = 9;
          int sum = (-1) + 2 - 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 78 + 9;
          int sum2 = (-1) + 2;
        if(b2>=a) //если верно то заходим
        {
           cout<<"УСПЕХ"<<endl; 
        }    
        else if(b>=a) //иначе проверяем это и если верното заходим
        {
            cout <<"hellol word\n";
        }   
        else if(b2<=d9)// //иначе проверяем это и если верното заходим
        {
             cout<<"programing"<< endl;
        }
        cout <<sum<<endl;
        cout << sum2<< endl;         

  return 0;
}
```

про операторы ветвления можно посмотреть [тут](https://code-live.ru/post/cpp-if-else/), но лучше у [Страуструпа](https://www.livelib.ru/author/129/latest-bjorn-straustrup) посмотреть он доступно рассказывает.